# Handling concurrency

Tags: javascript

The following code clearly has concurrency issues.

```
var a, b, c, d;

function f1() {
    var randomValue = Math.random();
    a = b = randomValue;
    setTimeout(function() {
        expect(a == b && b == randomValue);
    }, Math.round(Math.random() * 1000));
}
function f2() {
    var randomValue = Math.random();
    b = c = randomValue;
    setTimeout(function() {
        expect(b == c && c == randomValue);
    }, Math.round(Math.random() * 1000));
}
function f3() {
    var randomValue = Math.random();
    c = d = randomValue;
    setTimeout(function() {
        expect(c == d && d == randomValue);
    }, Math.round(Math.random() * 1000));
}
function f4() {
    var randomValue = Math.random();
    d = a = randomValue;
    setTimeout(function() {
        expect(d == a && a == randomValue);
    }, Math.round(Math.random() * 1000));
}

f1(); f2(); f2(); f4();
```

This can be solved by sandwiching all the functions between `wait` and `signal` of a semaphore. However that approach isn't the best and most efficient, because `f1()` and `f3()` can run simultaneously without encountering any problems, and so can `f2()` and `f4()`. And also I would prefer taking advantage of javascripts event loop rather than using semaphores. What is the best way to solve this? And how can the solution be extended to more functions with more variables?

Comment: You mean `f2()` and `f4()` right?

Comment: Should you use some sort of queue for timeouts to keep it synchronous ? also you can always lock parts of your methods